# Lower bound of the derivative $(f*g_\sigma)'$ at the zero-crossing point

Tags: real-analysis, gaussian, convolution

I am stuck with the following problem. Let consider $f$ a smooth real function such that:

- $f$ is negative before 0,
- $f$ is positive after 0,
- we have $|f'(0)|>0$.

Let $\sigma>0$ and $g_\sigma$ the gaussian function with mean 0 and deviation $\sigma$. We know that the convolution $f*g_\sigma$ has a unique zero denoted $x_\sigma$. My question is the following, can we find two real numbers $K>0$ and $n\in\mathbb{R}$  such that:

$$\forall \sigma>0, |(f*g_\sigma)'(x_\sigma)|\geq K\sigma^n.$$

Idealy, $n$ should not depend on $f$ but conversly, it seems reasonable to think that $K$ could depend on $f$..

Informally, I would like to find a speed of decrease of the derivative at the root $x_\sigma$.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: (i) Do you want $K>0$? (ii) Are $K$ and $n$ allowed to depend on $f$? (Using a non-specified term "constant" should be avoided.)

Comment: Thank you very much for asking clarifications @IosifPinelis, I have updated the post.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I think $n$ should depend on $f$. To imagine two different cases: if $f(x) = \sinh(x)$, then the derivative $(f \star g)'(0)$ should be increasing in $\sigma$. If $f(x) = \arctan(x)$, then $(f \star g)'(0)$ should be decreasing in $\sigma$.

Comment: Thank you Samuel for your interest. What I'm looking at is not the value of derivative in 0. I am looking to the value of the derivative, indeed, but at the zero of the convolution (denoted $x_\sigma$) $f*g_\sigma$. Maybe I didn't understand your remark.

Comment: Hi Gaetano, I believe whenever $f(x)$ is an odd function, the unique zero of $f \star g_\sigma$ is zero. Both the examples I gave, i.e. sihn and arctan, are odd.

Comment: Hi Samuel, I didn't notice that the zero of your specific examples were 0 with the odd peoperty. I do think like you now that $n$ should depend on $f$. However, I couldn't find any result on that...